# Moving Mail Messaged with Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I 'm doing mail processing with spring-integration. I got the receiving part working, but I would like to move the messages to different folders after processing.

Unfortunately, the MimeMessages received from the Adapter are not 'real' javax.mail.Message, but an IntegrationMimeMessage (in AbstractMailReceiver)

Is there a way to access the 'javax.mail.Message' so that I can move them with plain JavaMail? Or does spring-integration provide an adapter that can move messages ? Could not find any in the documentation.

Comment: `IntegrationMimeMessage extends javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`, which `extendsd javax.mail.Message`. So, what is the problem do you have there? Thanks